# Django rest framework-delete user but Table doesn't exist

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

> Table AWSIOt.User_set_user doesn't exist

[image to show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKcLa.png)

Hello, everybody, this is my first post.
I tried to delete a user by using user.delete(). However, it didn;t find user from table auth_user.
It looked for user from project.appname_user. I didn't create model user in my app and i writed "from django.contrib.auth.models import User" in top of my view file.
here are all my code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .head import *


class UserDeleteView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id')
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            user.delete()
            return Response(Return_msg())
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(Return_msg(None, True, 'Failed, user does not exist!!!'))
```

so, how can i fix it???

Comment: Did You execute makemigrations and migrate commands?

Comment: Actually,i did. I can even update user's data, and table auth_user will change. However, it failed when i wanted to delete a instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank. Your bug is probably related to the fact you're using wildcard import `from .head import *`. That might be causing namespace collision with `User`.

I would recommend you to consider using `delete` method from `APIView` as the snippet below:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import Http404


class UserDetailsView(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("user/<int:pk>/", views.UserDetailsView.as_view(), name="details_user"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you anway, i fixed it at last. Your comment is also a good idea. There are some common packages that i will use in every view file. So, I added them in a file called head.py.